# Drawing a helix effect in Unreal

Tags: unreal-4, materials

i want to draw/graph an equation(like sinusoidal signal or any parametric equation) in UE4. I don't know if that is possible. I looked for it but found almost nothing. here is what i found most related and wanted to achieve
https://oliverm-h.blogspot.com/2014/12/ue4-material-graphing-functions.html

the problem is i can't understand how he did it.

Anyone have the idea or any kind of help please?

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you walk us through exactly what you don't understand about the linked resource? What step do you find you get stuck on? This focus can help ensure we don't just repeat the same unclear explanation, but actually get to the underlying knowledge gap that's in your way.

Comment: in the linked resource, the blueprint version is provided. The gap is i can't understand the code( HLSL i guess). I tried to replicate the network of nodes provided there in my material blueprint but couldn't plot the equation though i could plot the grid.

Comment: oh i just saw your profile. I think you are the right person for my problem. I want to replicate a battle field using UE4. I am very new to this engine but studying as fast as i can. The game mechanics is as follow. first i can get the enemies' distance then using that distance as a parameter i want to graph an equation of a radio signal and distribution function. maybe there is another way of doing that than using materials. i hope you understand my point.

Comment: What kind of distribution function? Can you show us an example of what you want to see drawn on screen?

Comment: oh i thought i can put pictures here. Actually the equation could be a typical  electromagnetic signal in helical shape. 
1. https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.wccftech.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F12%2FFRB_nrao.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwccftech.com%2Fmysterious-radio-signals-detected%2F&docid=7unSn5GorIQAWM&tbnid=XTBpScM_XsSogM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjngL3Vka_hAhWHu54KHZnkDtIQMwhuKAUwBQ..i&w=1200&h=873&hl=en&authuser=0&bih=708&biw=1536&q=radio%20signals&ved=0ahUKEwjngL3Vka_hAhWHu54KHZnkDtIQMwhuKAUwBQ&iact=mrc&uact=8

Comment: sorry for late reply

Comment: https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fnordiasoft.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2015%2F08%2FEW-Image.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fnordiasoft.com%2Fknowledge-center%2Fapplication-domains%2Felectronic-warfare%2F&docid=p_cBLa8IB_kPKM&tbnid=MRToK8vWpXS2nM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwi1gM-ykq_hAhWNhJ4KHXHYDYQQMwikAShWMFY..i&w=263&h=192&hl=en&authuser=0&bih=708&biw=1536&q=electromagnetic%20radar%20signals&ved=0ahUKEwi1gM-ykq_hAhWNhJ4KHXHYDYQQMwikAShWMFY&iact=mrc&uact=8
systems like this one to draw lines and the last one is to draw simple sinusoidal signal with only one parameter as a variable.

Comment: That looks like a more specific ask than "graphing / plotting an equation" — I recommend using the edit link to update your question to something like "Drawing a helix effect in Unreal" with example images like these embedded in the question itself.

Comment: okay.let me do that though i want to graph other equations too.